# How to capture return prior to exception

Tags: exception, powershell, return-value

Is it possible to capture the output created by a function which also causes an exception?

```
function functionWhichCreatesOutputThenCausesAnException() {
    "hello"
    1/0
    "world"
}

try { 
    $result = functionWhichCreatesOutputThenCausesAnException 
} catch {
    $($error[0])
}
```

The output created by my function is displayed within my terminal.  I want to capture "hello".  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function functionWhichCreatesOutputThenCausesAnException() {
    "hello"
    1/0
    "world"
}

try { 
    $result = @()
    functionWhichCreatesOutputThenCausesAnException | foreach {$result += $_}
} catch {
    $($error[0])
}
```

Comment: Works for me too.  FWIW, it also works when executing a code block (rather than just calling a function).  Thanks!